Error 1053 when trying to start the service in Windows Service
I can't start a service that I created in C++Builder using the TService class.
I wrote a service that does nothing and I want to start it, but the service does not start. I register the service and start it in the command line. The command sc start MyService is executed without error, but the service status is starting and does not change to running. During service startup, the instruction in the ServiceStart() function records an error:

The service process could not connect to the service controller

When starting the service in the 'Services' window I get the error:

Windows could not start the Folder Backup Service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
signal in a timely manner.

I changed the service operation to Start and Stop functions with thread participation but the service still does not start and the error is the same. Even if I comment out the instructions from the OnStart and OnStop events
Here is my Service code:
Unit1.cpp:
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TService1 *Service1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TService1::TService1(TComponent* Owner): TService(Owner)
{
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __stdcall ServiceController(unsigned CtrlCode)
{
    Service1->Controller(CtrlCode);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

TServiceController __fastcall TService1::GetServiceController(void)
{
    return (TServiceController) ServiceController;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Start serwisu
void __fastcall TService1::ServiceStart(TService *Sender, bool &Started)
{
    BackupThread = new TFolderBackupThread(true); 
    BackupThread->Start(); 
    Started = true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TService1::ServiceStop(TService *Sender, bool &Stopped)
{
    if (BackupThread) {
        BackupThread->Terminate(); 
        BackupThread->WaitFor();   
        delete BackupThread;
        BackupThread = nullptr;
    }
    Stopped = true;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TService1::ServiceShutdown(TService *Sender)
{
    ServiceStop(Sender, *(new bool())); 
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Project1.cpp:
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <Vcl.SvcMgr.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <tchar.h>
USEFORM("Unit1.cpp", Service1); /* TService: File Type */
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define Application Svcmgr::Application
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        // Windows 2003 Server requires StartServiceCtrlDispatcher to be
        // called before CoRegisterClassObject, which can be called indirectly
        // by Application.Initialize. TServiceApplication->DelayInitialize allows
        // Application->Initialize to be called from TService->Main (after
        // StartServiceCtrlDispatcher has been called).
        //
        // Delayed initialization of the Application object may affect
        // events which then occur prior to initialization, such as
        // TService->OnCreate. It is only recommended if the ServiceApplication
        // registers a class object with OLE and is intended for use with
        // Windows 2003 Server.
        //
         Application->DelayInitialize = true;
        //
        if ((!Application->DelayInitialize) || (Application->Installing()))
        {
            Application->Initialize();
        }
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TService1), &Service1);
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Sysutils::ShowException(&exception, System::ExceptAddr());
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch(Exception &exception)
        {
            Sysutils::ShowException(&exception, System::ExceptAddr());
        }
        }
    return 0;
}


Did you debug it?  (see: How to debug an external process under C++ Builder?)

One major problem with your code is that your OnExecute event handler is empty.  It is not processing any SCM requests at all.
When an OnExecute event handler is NOT assigned, TService will process SCM requests automatically for you.  However, if an event handler IS assigned then it MUST call ServiceThread->ProcessRequests(false) periodically to process pending requests, eg:
void __fastcall TService1::ServiceExecute(TService *Sender)
{
    while (!ServiceThread->Terminated)
    {
        ServiceThread->ProcessRequests(false);
        // do other work...
        Sleep(10);
    }
}

Ideally, you should NEVER use an OnExecute event handler.  If you want your service to do actual work, it is better to use the OnStart event to create a worker thread instead, and then use the OnStop/OnShutdown events to terminate that thread, and optionally use the OnPause/OnContinue events to pause/resume that thread.

On a side note:

why are you logging the startup as an error?

your OnStart event handler does not need to call ReportStatus(), as the status will be reported to the SCM when the event handler exits.


void __fastcall TService1::ServiceStart(TService *Sender, bool &Started)
{
    LogMessage("Service started successfully", EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
    Started = true; // Serwis uruchomiony
}

